# Cythonizing string array comparison function to be applied to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, cython

I am just getting started with Cython and would appreciate some pointers as to how to approach this process. I have identified a speed bottleneck in my code and would like to optimize the performance of a specific operation.

I have a pandas DataFrame `trades` that looks like this:

```
                              Codes    Price  Size
Time
2015-02-24 15:30:01-05:00     R6,IS  11.6100   100
2015-02-24 15:30:01-05:00     R6,IS  11.6100   100
2015-02-24 15:30:01-05:00     R6,IS  11.6100   100
2015-02-24 15:30:01-05:00            11.6100   375
2015-02-24 15:30:01-05:00     R6,IS  11.6100   100
...                             ...      ...   ...
2015-02-24 15:59:55-05:00     R6,IS  11.5850   100
2015-02-24 15:59:55-05:00     R6,IS  11.5800   200
2015-02-24 15:59:55-05:00         T  11.5850   100
2015-02-24 15:59:56-05:00     R6,IS  11.5800   175
2015-02-24 15:59:56-05:00     R6,IS  11.5800   225

[5187 rows x 3 columns]
```

I have a `numpy` array called `codes`:

```
array(['4', 'AP', 'CM', 'BP', 'FA', 'FI', 'NC', 'ND', 'NI', 'NO', 'PT',
       'PV', 'PX', 'SD', 'WO'],
      dtype='|S2')
```

I need to filter `trades` such that if any of the values in `codes` is included in `trades['Codes']` that row is excluded. Currently I am doing this:

```
ix = trades.Codes.str.split(',').apply(lambda cs: not any(c in excludes for c in cs))
trades = trades[ix]
```

However, this is too slow and I need to make it faster. I want to use cython (as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) or maybe [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), it seems like cython is the better option.

I basically need a function like this:

```
def isinCodes(codes_array1, codes_array2):

    for x in codes_array1:
        for y in codes_array2:
            if x == y: return True

    return False
```

What types do I need to use when cythonizing?

Comment: why not use set.intersection?

Comment: Your algorithm is quadratic, cython  is not going to help that much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily vectorizable.

Construct a frame, I took 100000 * your example, 1M rows.

```
In [76]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
date      1000000 non-null datetime64[ns]
code      900000 non-null object
price     1000000 non-null float64
volume    1000000 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 38.1+ MB

In [77]: df2.head()   
Out[77]: 
                 date   code  price  volume
0 2015-02-24 20:30:01  R6,IS  11.61     100
1 2015-02-24 20:30:01  R6,IS  11.61     100
2 2015-02-24 20:30:01  R6,IS  11.61     100
3 2015-02-24 20:30:01    NaN  11.61     375
4 2015-02-24 20:30:01  R6,IS  11.61     100
```

This code would actually be: `df2.code.str.split(',',expand=True)`, but there is a perf issue ATM, going to be fixed for 0.16.2, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10090). So this code does this splitting in a very performant way.

```
In [78]: result = DataFrame([ [ s ] if not isinstance(s, list) else s for s in df2.code.str.split(',') ],columns=['A','B'])

In [79]: %timeit DataFrame([ [ s ] if not isinstance(s, list) else s for s in df2.code.str.split(',') ],columns=['A','B'])
1 loops, best of 3: 941 ms per loop

In [80]: result.head()
Out[80]: 
     A     B
0   R6    IS
1   R6    IS
2   R6    IS
3  NaN  None
4   R6    IS
```

I added 'T' to the end of the isin

```
In [81]: isin                     
Out[81]: 
['4',
 'AP',
 'CM',
 'BP',
 'FA',
 'FI',
 'NC',
 'ND',
 'NI',
 'NO',
 'PT',
 'PV',
 'PX',
 'SD',
 'WO',
 'T']
```

Results

```
In [82]: df2[(result.A.isin(isin) | result.A.isin(isin))].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100000 entries, 7 to 7
Data columns (total 4 columns):
date      100000 non-null datetime64[ns]
code      100000 non-null object
price     100000 non-null float64
volume    100000 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 3.8+ MB

In [83]: df2[(result.A.isin(isin) | result.A.isin(isin))].head()
Out[83]: 
                 date code   price  volume
7 2015-02-24 20:59:55    T  11.585     100
7 2015-02-24 20:59:55    T  11.585     100
7 2015-02-24 20:59:55    T  11.585     100
7 2015-02-24 20:59:55    T  11.585     100
7 2015-02-24 20:59:55    T  11.585     100
```

The actual operation is much faster than the splitting to get here.

```
In [84]: %timeit df2[(result.A.isin(isin) | result.A.isin(isin))]       
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
```